# Constantly checking existence of dictionary elements in Python: a better way?

Tags: python

I use Python dictionaries to count words in a corpus:

`words[a]` = number of times I saw `a` in the corpus.

Every time before incrementing a counter (`words[a] += 1`), I need to check a condition: 
does the dictionary entry `words[a]` actually exists?

My code:

```
    if a in words:
      words[a] += 1
    else:
      words[a] = 1
```

It there a way to improve it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For Python >= 2.5 you can use [defaultdict](http://docs.python.org/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) instead of dict:

```
 from collections import defaultdict
 words = defaultdict(int)
 corpus = ["your", "word", "corpus"]
 for a in corpus:
    words[a]+=1
 print words
```

For Python >= 2.7 you can use [Counter](http://docs.python.org/library/collections.html#collections.Counter):

```
from collections import Counter
corpus = ["your", "word", "corpus"]
words = Counter(corpus)
print words
```

Comment: Might be worth pointing out `collections.Counter` as well.

Comment: @WinstonEwert: excellent suggestion, updated the answer.

Comment: For insanely old versions of Python, there's also the option of `words.setdefault(a, 0) += 1`.

Comment: For Python < 2.7 you can use this Counter: http://code.activestate.com/recipes/576611/ .